# rpm.spec hide warning that comes after %post

Tags: linux, rpm, rpm-spec

I'm trying to solve this problem for a few days now but still nothing...

Let's say for example this is my `upgrade.sh:`

```
Finished upgrading...
```

And this is my `rpm.spec` file:

```
Name: Hi
Summary:  Discover Server
Source: %{name}-%{version}.%{release}.tar.gz
Version:    %{version}
Release:    %{release}
Group:   Discover Server
License: Commercial
Vendor:  Software
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-root
Obsoletes: %{name}

%description
 Discover Server

%prep

%setup -n %{name} -q

%install
something that is not relevant

%post
sh ./upgrade.sh
echo "finished post"

%pre

%preun

%clean
echo "cleaning"
rm -rf ($RPM_BUILD_ROOT) &> /dev/null

%files -f %{name}-%{version}-filelist
```

Now  I got `example.rpm` file.
After I'm running the command rpm -U example.rpm
this is the output I'm getting:

```
Finished upgrading
Finished post

warning: XYXYXY: remove failed: No such file or directory
warning: XXXX: remove failed: No such file or directory
```

Everything works fine with the upgrade, my only problem is that I don't want to show the warnings that coming after the post commanded is finish.
How can I do it? Every time we release a new upgrade the name of the files are different, cause they have the version name on them so maybe that's the problem.

Is there an easy way to make these warning messages just to go to dev/null or something?
Also it is important to see the `"Finished upgrading..."` message.

Comment: Is `./upgrade.sh` erasing the files that RPM should be handling? It shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning means that `rpm` is trying to remove the files from the old package, but they are not on the file system anymore. So you should ask yourself why that is so, and what to do about this:

- Are you removing them manually? Don't, and let `rpm` remove them for you.
- Are they not guaranteed to be on the system? In that case you could make them `%ghost` files. These files will be removed when present, but you won't get no warning if they don't exist. ([more on %ghost files here](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html))

```
%files
%ghost /path/to/file-that-might-or-not-be-there
```

If you wonder why this error appears after the `%post` section is executed, then here is a good read for you where the order of all scriptlets during an upgrade is well shown: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/#ordering

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for the answer. I will try to use the ghost file and update if it works. Do you think it will work for folders too?

Comment: Yes I'm quite sure it should work for folders as well